# how to call a controller method when dropdownlist is selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the code here.How can I call a controller method.

```
<div class="uLeft">
    Select Institution:
    @Html.DropDownList("Sortby", new SelectListItem[]
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option1", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option2", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option3", Value = "3" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option4", Value = "4" }
    },
    new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" })
</div>
```

Comment: you write an ajax call in CallChangefunc with the url to you controller method( which should be marked as post or get) or use jquery post or load depending o what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You already have function `CallChangefunc(this.value)` on change.

Next thing you are going to declare this function as (post example) -

```
<script>
    function CallChangefunc(value) {
        $.post('http://localhost/{controller}/{action}', { sortBy: value }, function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide id to your dropdown list

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sortby", new SelectListItem[]
 {
         new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option1", Value = "1" }, 
         new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option2", Value = "2" }, 
         new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option3", Value = "3" }, 
         new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option4", Value = "4" }
 }, 
 new { id = "ddlInstitution" })
```

and your jquery code like this

```
$("#ddlInstitution").on('change', function () {

    var selValue = $('#ddlInstitution').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/{controller}/{action}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { method parameter name : selValue },
        success: function (data) {

       },
       failure: function (data) {
            alert('oops something went wrong');
       }
   });
});
```